# is any Observer In magento After Payment method is Selected..before order place

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, payment-methods

I need to know observer after payment method select in magento.
Basically I need to check some attribute value in added cart product after payment method is selected.
Basically I need to know observer after payment method selected.
If my selected method is Cash On Delivery... then I want to validate some attribute in added cart product....and if that true then ...place the order if false then want to redirect cart page with error Message....
Basically Any observer which can be fire after payment method is selected in magento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with the `sales_quote_payment_import_data_before`.
This one is dispatched in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment::importData` that is called by `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::savePayment` that is called by `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::savePaymentAction`, which is the action called when you press `continue` on the checkout after selecting the payment method.

Comment: its also working in one step checkout ?

Comment: I don't know...it depends on the extension

Comment: by which method we can get payment method here..can you explain pls

Comment: @Marius can you please mention the events for Magento 2 to do the same.

Comment: I think it's the same.

Comment: @Marius but in Magento 2, "Mage" is not using.... you are Magento Pro man....plz help me.

Comment: The event name is the same `sales_quote_payment_import_data_before`. It is dispatched in `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment::importData`. It's the same as in magento 1. Just the class names have backslashes instead of underscore

Comment: ok Thanks.. let me check.